# How to check if perpendicular intersects segment? C#

Tags: c#, math, geometry

I have to check if perpendicular exists.

I am using one line segment defined by two points

- T<sub>1</sub>(x<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>1</sub>)..T<sub>2</sub>(x<sub>2</sub>,y<sub>2</sub>)

and then I have to put perpendicular so it goes to the third point

- T<sub>3</sub>(x<sub>3</sub>,y<sub>3</sub>)

This is working fine but I do not know how to check if the perpendicular even exists.

### Calculating the perpendicular intersection

I calculated T<sub>P</sub>(x<sub>4</sub>,y<sub>4</sub>) (point on T<sub>1</sub>,T<sub>2</sub> line) with:

```
double dx = x2 - x1;
double dy = y2 - y1;
double mag = Math.Sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
dx /= mag;
dy /= mag;

double lambda = (dx * (x3 - x1)) + (dy * (y3 - y1));
rx1 = (dx * lambda) + x1;
ry1 = (dy * lambda) + y1;
```

This works fine:

[image]

This should throw an error:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean? Any 2D line has infinite number of perpendicular lines (and exactly one through a given point).

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected results.

Comment: Two possible approaches: (A) Treat line as infinite. Calculate intersection of perpendicular from point T3 and determine if intersection point is between T1,T2. Or, (B) Calculate angles of lines T1,T3 and T2,T3 with respect to line (T1-T2), and with same rotation direction. If both angles are >90 or both angles <90, then no perpendicular from T3 to a point between T1,T2. If one angle is >90, and other <90, then perpendicular exist. If one of the angles happens to be 90 degrees, well...

Comment: I meant line segment. I also added the pictures and sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: Then calculate an intersection point and see if it is between T1 and T2.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to check if the perpendicular exists then you can do the following (based on your sketch):

1. Create vectors *v1* (T1-T2), *v2* (T1-T3) and *v3* (T2-T3).
2. Evaluate angles *a1* (v1-v2) and *a2* (v1-v3).
3. If the absolute value of *a1* or *a2* is larger than 90º, no perpendicular will fall between T1 and T2.

Evaluating angles between vectors is trivial: look up [vector dot product or scalar product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).

Comment: So that means I have to check the angle between a1 and a2?

Comment: @FatTommy no, you evaluate the angle between vectors `v1` and `v2` and the angle between vectors `v1` and `v3`.